# Writing all the values of a dictionary in columns

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in which each key has list as a value. The thing is, number of elements of each list is different for each key. Instead of writing as Rows using csv, i am writing them in columns. Lets say the format of the dictionary is as below:

```
myDict = {'cli1':['9','1'], 'cli2':['6','8','4'], 'cli3':['7']}
```

I wanted to print in a .csv file in the following fashion:

```
cli1    cli2    cli3
9       6       7  
1       8
        4
```

I wrote the following program to accomplish the task:

```
with open('PduDictOut.csv','wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(myDict.keys())
    for row in zip(*myDict.values()):
            writer.writerow(list(row))
file.close()
```

But this program is giving me the below output:

```
 cli1    cli2    cli3 
 9       6       7
```

My program is taking the key with minimum number of items in its list and its giving me the same number of elements for all the keys. How can i change the program to generate the output like i wanted. Thanks in advance. Help is very much appreciated. BTW i am using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the third list only has one item, `zip` will truncate the result to one tuple.

Use `itertools.izip_longest` with a fill value instead:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

for row in izip_longest(*myDict.values(), fillvalue=''):
    ...
```

Comment: `.keys()` and `.values()` will iterate in the same order if you don't add/remove keys in between.

Comment: @gnibbler Is this empirical knowledge or part of the language specification?

Comment: @Hyperboreus, It's part of the [spec](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items). I think it's been discussed on SO sometime ago.

Comment: @gnibbler: Thanks. I thought it was just for CPython.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
myDict = {'cli1':['9','1'], 'cli2':['6','8','4'], 'cli3':['7']}

values = map(None, *myDict.values())
```

output: `[('6', '7', '9'), ('8', None, '1'), ('4', None, None)]`

Change bit of logic to handle None while writing it to csv.

Comment: I think you're better off adding the extra logic to the map: `map(lambda *v: [x or '' for x in v], *myDict.values())`